# Что такое javascript:void(0);?

Tags: javascript

Ребят, всем привет.
Есть сайт. Там есть ссылка с `href = "javascript:void(0);"`. Что это? И как узнать, на что ссылается, и где этот скрипт? Есть доступ ко всем исходникам.

Comment: Это обычная заглушка. В данном случае букмарклет. Предотвращение стандартного поведения ссылки.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`void(0)` — это выражение, получающееся приведением типа константы 0 к `void`. То есть простое ничего не значащее выражение.

Ссылка в таком виде просто ничего не делает. (И это популярная идиома, кстати.) Не исключено, скрипт на странице модифицирует `href` позже, чтобы ссылка делала что-то более вразумительное; но пока/если этот скрипт не пробежал, ссылка останется такой, как есть.

Comment: Например, есть такая ссылка `<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="get-yml-market  tool-tip-top" title="<?php echo $lang['T_TIP_UPLOAD_YA'];?>"><span><?php echo $lang['PROD_UPLOAD_YA'];?></span></a>`. Она работает только в платном пакете. Хочу узнать, какой скрипт отрабатывается!

Comment: @duddeniska: Это вам надо остальные исходники смотреть, в приведённой части ничего информативного нет.

Comment: `undefined` слишком долго писать?

Comment: @Alex78191: Это не ко мне, в вопросе упоминается именно `void(0)`.

Comment: @Alex78191 `void 0` занимает меньше букв чем `undefined` и это может влиять на конечный размер скрипта. При использовании тулов типа typescript/babel это более очевидно.

Answer (score 14):

Когда браузер переходит по ссылке `javascript:`, то заменяет содержание страницы на возвращаемое значение, кроме случаев, когда вернулось `undefined`. Оператор `void` всегда возвращает это самое значение `undefined`.

Подробно (на англ.): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

Answer (score 8):

В старых браузерах была возможность создать переменную с именем undefined. Соответственно, чтобы получить значение undefined используется такая конструкция. Конструкции void можно передать любое число/тип переменной - void 123,void [] так же вернет undefined.

Answer (score 8):

Конструкцию типа `href = "javascript:void(0);"` используют обычно тогда, когда вместе обычного перехода по ссылке должен сработать js скрипт.

Примеры таких случаев - открытие модального окна, отправка/получение данных с помощью ajax или необходимость проверить какие-то данные с помощью js перед тем как совершить переход по этой ссылке.

Чтобы найти скрипт, который срабатывает при клике на эту ссылку стоит посмотреть в режиме инспектора. Пример как это можно сделать, на скриншоте:
[image: Пример как увидеть обрабатывающий js скрипт]

Answer (score 5):

`href = "javascript:void(0);"` добавляют, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку, которая выполняет не свою прямую функцию, страница не прокручивалась вверх, а всё оставалось на месте

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае - это то же самое, что return false;

Comment: Нравится видеть в консоли `Uncaught SyntaxError`?

Answer (score -1):

Запрет отправки данных на сервер.

Comment: Это, конечно же, неправда.